# how to integrate UrlRewritingFilter with Struts 2.X

Tags: url-rewriting, struts2, wildcard

1) Is there a way to integrate UrlRewritingFilter with Struts2 **tiles**.i think there is a problem with 
listeners in web xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>listener.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

2) how to use struts2 advanced wildcard mapping to write better urls with actions.anybody can share a working example please?

thanks.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you need to configure your rewrite filter

### web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>WARN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please note the change done to S2 filter

Add a `rewrite.xml` file under `WEB-INF` with entry like

```
<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
    <from>^/some/olddir/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/very/newdir/$1</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

For more details refer to there [documents](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/2.6/).
There is one more option to create clean  URL using `NamedVariablePatternMatcher`,for details refer to this blog for example and understanding

- [better-urls-with-struts2](http://www.struts2.info/displaycontent/content/better-urls-with-struts2)